# Arithmetic lattices are finitely presented

Tags: algebraic-groups, lattices

In the book "Kazhdan's Property (T)" by Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette, the following is stated on p.6 of the introduction:

"*Of course, it is classical that arithmetic lattices are finitely generated, indeed finitely presented.*"

They cite Thm. 6.12 in "Arithmetic subgroups of algebraic groups" by Borel-Harish-Chandra for this. However, that theorem states that if $G$ is an algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $G(\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated. Why is it also finitely presented?

Comment: A better reference is to the work of Borel and Serre who construct a compactification of the associated locally symmetric space/orbifold as a manifold/orbifold with corners. Finite presentability (and much more) follows.

Comment: Moishe provides the argument when $G$ is reductive. For the general case, one has to boil down to the latter case. Namely in this case, $U$ being the unipotent radical, this boils down to the result for $G/U$, the lattice being, up to finite index, extension with kernel $U(\mathbf{Z})$ (which is f.g. nilpotent, hence finitely presented) and quotient $(G/U)(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your replies!